# Is there a definitive list of which AWS data is safe/unsafe to store in source control?

Tags: amazon-web-services, version-control

I'm making a service that heavily uses AWS cloud services, which requires several user specific pieces of information to interact with, eg.

- Region names
- Cognito user pool ID
- Cognito client ID
- Lambda ARNs
- Lambda function names
- API Gateway ID
- S3 bucket names

etc.

Obviously passwords, secret keys and access tokens aren't safe to be stored in source control, but there seems to be conflicting advice on which other bits of data are safe and which should be stored in environment variables or provided by other means.

Question is...is there a definitive list of which data is safe and which is unsafe to go in source control?

Many thanks

Comment: Theoretically, any of the above is 'acceptable' to be exposed since that information alone cannot grant access. If those details were accidentally exposed, it would not necessarily be something you would need to 'correct'. You are correct that passwords, secret keys and STS tokens should be protected.

Comment: Some advice about what to store, where, is not really about what is "safe" (secure) but rather about good practice, future-proofing, separation of concerns, etc.  Arguably, anything that varies across deployments/environments should be provided to the code via clean abstractions (such as environment variables, or the SSM Parameter Store) but this often isn't about safety/security/secrecy.  In light of the risk of this question being closed by the community as too broad or primarily opinion based, can you cite specific examples of the conflicting advice, to make the question less abstract?